# MySQL syntax to insert new rows based on mixed variables plus select records from another table

Tags: php, mysql

Question is how to write a MySQL statement that is a combination of variables and data from another table.

For example, for all the records in table `contractor`, I want to insert `id` and `name` from `contractor` into table `renewals`… plus add the variables `$foo` and `$bar` into the columns `foo` and `bar` on the same insert

```
$foo = 'foo';
$bar = 'bar'

INSERT INTO renewals (id, name, foo, bar)
SELECT id, name FROM contractor
```

I'm drawing a blank on how to finish writing the statement to also add `$foo` and `$bar` which are not coming from table `contractor` into each of those new rows.

Also, `renewals` has a composite key based on `(id, name, foo)` so I need to add

```
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bar = '$bar'
```

at the end of the statement.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$query = "INSERT INTO renewals (id, name, foo, bar) "
. "SELECT id, name, '$foo', '$bar' FROM contractor "
. "ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE bar = '$bar'";
```

It doesn't matter that `$foo` and `$bar` don't come from table `contractor`.